# Debugging a formula on Excel for Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos

The following is returning a #VALUE! error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A12,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3))
```

The aim of this formula is to take the sum of all the values that match each macronutrient under "Daily Tally" in the "food tracker" worksheet -- e.g. "Kcal". Each of those values are broken down in the worksheet "nutrition by portion" by the type of food, e.g. "almond butter". Images below for additional context.

Based on feedback, here are the worksheets and named ranges as markdown tables :

"nutrition by portion" worksheet (abridged)

| Foodstuff | weight (grams or ml) | Kcal | Animal Protein (g) | Plant Protein (g) | Sodium (mg) | Potassium (mg) | Fat (g) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| almond butter | 1.00 | 5.94 | 0.00 | 0.22 | 0.00 | 7.47 | 0.53 |
| almond cake | 1.00 | 3.55 | 0.00 | 0.08 | 2.74 | 3.48 | 0.30 |
| almond flour | 1.00 | 6.33 | 0.00 | 0.23 | 0.00 | 6.67 | 0.50 |
| almondmilk | 1.00 | 0.13 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.67 | 0.15 | 0.01 |
| almonds | 1.00 | 5.89 | 0.00 | 0.21 | 0.01 | 7.32 | 0.50 |

"food tracker" worksheet (refers to values in "nutrition by portion"):

| day of week | friday |
| --- | --- |
| meal number | 1 |
| almond butter | 30 |
| almond cake | 40 |
| almond flour | 10 |
| almondmilk | 5 |
| almonds | 2 |

| Daily Tally | Kcal |
| --- | --- |
|  | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH(@A:A,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Animal Protein (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A12,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Plant Protein (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A13,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Fat (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A14,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Saturated Fat (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A15,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Net Carbs (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A16,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Fiber (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A17,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Soluble Fiber (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A18,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Sugar (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A19,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Omega-3 (ALA) (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A20,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Monounsaturated Fat (g) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A21,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Sodium (mg) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A22,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Potassium (mg) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A23,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Calcium (mg) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A24,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |
| Iron (mg) | =SUMPRODUCT(IFNA(@OFFSET(AllFoodItems,MATCH(@DailyFoodItems,AllFoodItems,0)-1,MATCH($A25,Nutrients,0),1,1),0), OFFSET(DailyFoodItems,0,B$3)) |

| Named Range | Range Value | Refers to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DailyFooditems | {"almond butter"; "almond cake"; "almond flour";"almondmilk";"almonds"} | ='food tracker'!$A$4:$A$8 |
| AllFooditems | {"almond butter"; "almond cake"; "almond flour";"almondmilk";"almonds"} | ='nutrition by portion'!$A$2:$A$10 |
| Nutrients | {"weight (grams or ml)", "Kcal","Animal Protein (g)","Plant Protein (g)","Sodium (mg)","Potassium (mg)","Fat (g)"} | ='nutrition by portion'!$B$1:$AA$1 |

Please also see images for how the workbook is organized and name manager values.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: `MATCH($A12,Nutrients,0)` shouldn't that be `MATCH(@A:A,Nutrients,0)`?

Comment: @P.b., I've included data as you'd advised -- please let me know if anything else would help. Yes, the yellow figures represent the weight. The original formula (the Libre Office version) didn't use the @A:A range in the match: each macronutrient like "Kcals" is matched using a formula that references the specific value in the "food tracker" worksheet as opposed to a range.

Comment: You should **ask a question** before sending further reopen inquiries. Remember that this is a Q&A site and the intent should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the OFFSET, so it's no longer volatile.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B$4:B$8,INDEX('nutricion by portion'!B$2:AA$6,MATCH(DailyFoodItems,AllFooditems,0),MATCH(@A:A,Nutrients,0)))
```

You may want to make `B4:B8` dynamic, but you gave too little example data. Also  `'nutricion by portion'!B$2:AA$6` could become a named range. The thing with named ranges is: it makes formulas easy to read if you know what they are and where they are. If you don't, then actual ranges are better readable for an outsider.

If you're on Office 365 you may want to use `LET()`, where you can name ranges or arrays within the formula itself. This makes it better readable for anyone, if you use it right.

Comment: Appreciate your help, @P.b -- Your formula did indeed work for the data I shared and so I'll mark your response as the solution. It wasn't working initially in the complete dataset (from which I'd excerpted the data provided) and I am still working to find the problem. So a broader question is if there is a process to follow in the absence of the evaluator tool (again, not available for the MacOs version of Excel): some other debugging tool or process that can help Mac users?